# NGINX URL Redirect - Configuration

Tags: nginx

What should be the correct configuration , if i want to redirect any request for www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/page.

I tried couple of options but always ended up in an redirect loop.

Comment: You want request to `www.mydomain.com/any/url/` to be redirected to `www.mydomain.com/page`?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
rewrite ^/$ http://www.mydomain.com/page permanent;
```

If this was what you were using and it looped then there must be a redirect rule in place for /page.